# Why doesn't BURG replace GRUB?

Tags: grub2, bootloader, burg

BURG looks a lot better and user friendly than GRUB, at the same time it get the job done.

Why Ubuntu have not switched to it?

Comment: Can you explain why Burg looks better and is more user-friendly than Grub?  (As far as I know you can have a graphical menu in Grub 2 too, did you try and compare that?)

Comment: I doubt burg is as "powerful" maybe in the future they'll switch to burg.

Answer (score 23):

BURG is a one-man fork of GRUB.  GRUB is the primary project with an active development community.  I don't intend to ever switch Ubuntu to BURG; I would rather focus on improving GRUB.

Look at the commit activity of the two projects (quickest way: `bzr log lp:burg` vs. `bzr log lp:grub/grub2`).  BURG has only had five commits in the last six months - to all intents and purposes, it's moribund.  Over the same time period, GRUB has had just over five **hundred** commits.

BURG did some useful things with themes, although GRUB has most of that - it just doesn't ship them by default, which IIRC was due to licensing problems.  BURG supported a different installation mode which helped some people, but now that GRUB has Reed-Solomon encoding and the ability to skip certain sectors in the boot track this shouldn't generally be needed.  There are a handful of other small improvements.  None of them justify losing the fantastic GRUB community.

Incidentally, I'd thoroughly encourage reporting the reasons you feel BURG is superior to GRUB as bugs on GRUB.

Answer (score 20):

Because BURG is **not ready** to be deployed on this many machines. It's *very* early in it's development, and I'm sure later on, say when they have reached a beta version, people will start to look into it.

Check burgs [Project Page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/burg) to keep up with development(s).

As people have pointed out, the boot loader can be considered the most important part of a system. If it doesn't work correctly, none of your operating systems will start. This is why this type of software has to be extremely mature before it gets deployed on a massive scale.

Colin Watson (one of the Ubuntu grub maintainers) also has more information in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11863/why-doesnt-burg-replace-grub/20187#20187).

Comment: Just to add that you have to remember that the bootloader could be called the most important component of the Ubuntu stack - if it goes wrong you can't get into Ubuntu (or your other operating systems)! So such a major component needs to be fairly mature and well tested to ensure no breakage across the huge variety of devices Ubuntu is used on.

Comment: Yes indeed. And in this respect, GRUB is the Humber Bridge of software engineering. Its stability and correctness are tremendous.

Comment: It's definitly a work in progress.  Having multiple Kernels installed can make it much less useful than Grub and it doesn't always handle new Kernels being installed.

Answer (score 2):

Another, more current reason why BURG might not have been switched to is that it appears to be an abandoned project. The last commit to [trunk](https://code.launchpad.net/~bean123ch/burg/trunk) as of this writing was all the way back in 2010.

Without continued development, new features and - more importantly - bug fixes to make BURG work better with newer hardware and software simply aren't happening. Unless development resumes or the project is forked, there's little chance it will be accepted.